# Android won't write new line in text file

Tags: java, android, android-file

I am trying to write a new line to a text file in android.

Here is my code:

```
FileOutputStream fOut;
try {
    String newline = "\r\n";
    fOut = openFileOutput("cache.txt", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 

    osw.write(data);
    osw.write(newline);

    osw.flush();
    osw.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have tried `\n`, `\r\n` and I did also try to get the system property for a new line, neither of them work.

The data variable contains previously data from the same file.

```
String data = "";

try {
    FileInputStream in = openFileInput("cache.txt");   
    StringBuffer inLine = new StringBuffer();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in, "ISO8859-1");
    BufferedReader inRd = new BufferedReader(isr,8 * 1024);
    String text;

    while ((text = inRd.readLine()) != null) {
        inLine.append(text);
    }

    in.close();
    data = inLine.toString();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "don't work"? How do you check it? Also try replacing `data` with something simple like "foo" and check whether the variable contents cause problems.

Comment: When i open it in textedit, word or any other program. The new lines are not displayed.

Comment: Tried with dummy text it didn't work.

Comment: and you say that 1)the file is created 2)some data is written to it 3) new lines are not? Can you please try duplicating the two writes: `osw.write(data);   osw.write(newline);` I want to see if at least one new line will show.

Comment: @NikolajSvendsen What `data` variable contains? Do you expect the only new line at the end of file (according to your code)?

Comment: The data contains data from another file, i edited the above. Can it be something about that it skips the breaks when i read the first file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I executed a similar program and it worked for me. I observed a strange behavior though. It added those new lines to the file, however the cursor remained at the first line. If you want to verify, write a `String` after your newline characters, you will see that the `String` is written just below those new lines.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problems, tried every trick in the book.

My problem: the newline's were written, but while reading they were removed:

```
while (readString != null) {
                datax.append(readString);
                readString = buffreader.readLine();
            }
```

The file was read line by line and concatenated, so the newline's disappeared.

I did not look at the original file in Notepad or something because I didn't know where to look on my phone, and my logscreen used the code which removed the newline's :-(

So the simple soultion was to put it back while reading:

```
while (readString != null) {
                datax.append(readString);
                datax.append("\n");
                readString = buffreader.readLine();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and was unable to write a newline. Instead I use BufferdWritter to write a new line into the file and it works for me.
Here is a sample code sniplet:

```
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("cache.txt",0));
BufferedWriter bwriter = new BufferedWriter(out);
// write the contents to the file
bwriter.write("Input String"); //Enter the string here
bwriter.newLine();
```